# Running processing workflow in PyQGIS for every selected polygon separately in for loop

Tags: pyqgis, iteration

I would like to run the processing chain written in PyQGIS (as stated below) for every polygon that is extracted by the `extractbyexpression` separately. But, the code below does not do this for every polygon separately, but rather n times for all polygons together which results in wrong output (with n the number of extracted polygons).

Any thoughts on how to solve this? So for each extracted polygon, the workflow is run separately? I am new to PyQGIS.

```
openruimte = iface.addVectorLayer(....)

expression_divide = ['Area >= 10 and Area < 20']

selectbyexpr = processing.run("native:extractbyexpression",
                              {'EXPRESSION' : expression_divide[0],
                               'INPUT': openruimte,
                               'OUTPUT': 'memory:'})['OUTPUT']

for feature in selectbyexpr.getFeatures():
    x = feature["Area"] / 5
    selectbyexpr.select(feature.id())
    random_points = processing.run(
        "qgis:randompointsinsidepolygons",
        {'EXPRESSION': '20',
        'INPUT': QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(selectbyexpr.id(), selectedFeaturesOnly=True),
        'MIN_DISTANCE': 0.01,
        'OUTPUT': 'memory:', 
        'STRATEGY': 1})['OUTPUT']
    
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(random_points)
    
    cluster= processing.run(
        "native:kmeansclustering",
        {'CLUSTERS': x, 'FIELD_NAME': 'CLUSTER_ID', 'INPUT': random_points,
        'OUTPUT': 'memory:'})['OUTPUT']
    
    aggregate= processing.run("qgis:aggregate",
                              {'AGGREGATES' : [{'aggregate': 'array_agg', 'delimiter': ',', 'input': '"CLUSTER_ID"', 'length': 0, 'name': 'CLUSTER_ID', 'precision': 0, 'type': 2}],
                               'GROUP_BY' : '\"CLUSTER_ID\"',
                               'INPUT' : cluster,
                               'OUTPUT' : 'memory:'})['OUTPUT']
    
    centroid_aggr= processing.run("native:centroids",
                            {'ALL_PARTS': False,
                            'INPUT': aggregate,
                            'OUTPUT': 'memory:'})['OUTPUT']
```

As can be seen from the picture, only 1 output of the `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(random_points)` is shown, but it includes the random points for all selected polygons and not only for 1 selected polygon.
[image]

Comment: based on this code, I see no reason why parallel processing would give wrong data. Or is the for loop not iterating over the right object? what does `for f in selectbyexpr.getFeatures(); print(f)` return? If it prints a list of features that should solve it. What is your output and what would you expect?

Comment: @Thomas  It looks to me that you're in fact iterating through the selected set of features, but when you are doing your processing in the for loop, it doesn't seem like you're operating on only the f (feature) identified in the for loop, but the selected set (selectbyexpr).  You might have to get your first selection set outside the for loop and get a list of FIDs.  And then iterate over your FIDs in the for loop, completing another expression to select each feature by FID and then using that feature selection in the processing tools.  Just a thought.  I'll look at it closer if I have time.

Comment: @GevaertJoep, I updated my post with the 'print' statement. BryanTaylor actually summarizes the problem very well: " but when you are doing your processing in the for loop, it doesn't seem like you're operating on only the f (feature) identified in the for loop, but the selected set (selectbyexpr)" . This is exactly the problem I'm facing right now.

Comment: @Thomas, start with substituting "INPUT': selectbyexpr" by "INPUT': feature" in random_points expression

Comment: @BryanTaylor, I understand your suggestion and I'll try to translate it into code. However, since I've literally started some days ago with PyQGIS, it would be awesome if you could find some time to help me with the code :) . Thanks in advance (both of you)!

Comment: @Szym, I tried it, but it gave the following error: `core.QgsProcessingException: Unable to execute algorithm
Could not load source layer for INPUT: invalid value`

Answer (score 2):

You need to select the related feature in every loop and change `INPUT` value in `qgis:randompointsinsidepolygons` as in the following script. Otherwise, in every loop the tool uses all features in `selectbyexpr` layer.

```
...

for feature in selectbyexpr.getFeatures():
    x = feature["Area"] / 5
    selectbyexpr.select(feature.id()) # <-- add this line

    random_points = processing.run(
        "qgis:randompointsinsidepolygons",
         {'EXPRESSION': '20',
          # change INPUT like below
          'INPUT': QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(selectbyexpr.id(), selectedFeaturesOnly=True),
          'MIN_DISTANCE': 0.01,
          'OUTPUT': 'memory:', 
          'STRATEGY': 1})['OUTPUT']
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. However, when I run your code I get the following error message: " Could not load source layer for INPUT: output_939d2154_96d5_495b_ae94_0b965f32340e not found ". When I used `print(selectbyexpr.select(feature.id()))` in the for loop, I received n times 'None' as output... Do you know what the problem is and how to solve this?

Comment: It is OK you recevied `None`. `select` method returns `None` if it selects features or not.

Comment: What do `print(selectbyexpr)` and `print(selectbyexpr.id())` return before `for` loop?

Comment: `print(selectbyexpr)` results in:
<qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer object at 0x000001840CE768B8> and `print(selectbyexpr.id())` results in:
output_939d2154_96d5_495b_ae94_0b965f32340e

Comment: I don't receive that error. I couldn't figure it out. The script in the answer works without any error in my computer.

Comment: For one or the other reason, your code suddenly ran. However, the main problem was not solved by this code. I edited my post with your code. (Already thanks for the effort you made :) )